# Delete multiple documents in CouchDB

Tags: ios, couchdb, couchcocoa

I've a "best practice" question on CouchDB (actually I'm using TouchDB a CouchDB port to iOS), when using CouchCocoa framework.

I need to delete a bunch of documents that I get via a query.
I know 3 ways to do this:

1) put all the documents into an NSArray, then use [CouchDatabase deleteDocuments:]

2) foreach query rows call the delete method, like:
   for (CouchQueryRow* row in query.rows)
    [row.document DELETE];

3) create a query that emit the _id, _rev properties and add the _deleted property, then use the bulk update, like:
[couchDatabase putChanges:]

What's the better performance-wise? There's a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the HTTP API level, the fastest way to achieve this is to run a single batch request that provides the `_id` and current `_rev` of all documents to be removed.

Your job is to make sure that CouchCocoa actually does this — I know that CouchCocoa will try to cache the `_rev` of documents it reads, so if you are deleting documents that have just been read, `[CouchDatabase deleteDocuments:]` should be enough, otherwise you will have to `[CouchDatabase getDocumentsWithIDs:]` first.

**If your documents are very large**, it might become better to get the `_rev` using a view instead of a bulk fetch. This forces you to use `[CouchDatabase putChanges:]` to perform the bulk deletion. I don't know where the document size threshold lies, so you will have to benchmark this one.

Of course, you also need to decide what happens when a conflict occurs.